# Promises in angular2 with firebase

Tags: firebase, promise, angular, angular2-services

Can someone explain how to correctly implement promise in Angular2 and Firebase.

I've read some articles such as this https://www.firebase.com/blog/2016-01-21-keeping-our-promises.html

in my app.component.ts file i have this

```
export class AppComponent{
    players: Player[];

    constructor(private _playerService: PlayerService){}

    getPlayers(){
        this._playerService.getPlayers().then(res => this.players = res);
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.getPlayers();
    }
}
```

inside the player.service.ts file I have this

```
getPlayers() {
    this.playersRef.once('value', function (snap){
        return snap.val();
    });
}
```

I always get TypeError: this._playerService.getPlayers(...) is undefined

I also tried this as the article on top suggests

```
getPlayers() {
    var data;
    this.playersRef.once('value').then( function (snap){
        data = snap.val();
    });
    return data;
}
```

But then i get this: Error: Query.once failed: Was called with 1 argument. Expects at least 2. in [null]

I'm not sure how the article is working at all with .once('value').then()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem occurs because you are trying to using `.then` over a method which isn't using promise. Basically missed to return `promise` from `getPlayers` method, you should return promise from there to perform promise chaining using `.then` method over it.

Also don't use callback to return value from it(because callback are not capable of returning anything from it), use `.then` function over `.once` so that you can extend promise chain & will be able to return out data correctly.

**Code**

```
getPlayers() {
    //returned promise here
    return this.playersRef.once('value').then((snap) => {
        return snap.val();
    });
}
```

Comment: `.once()` is asynchronous that's why I used `.then` over it, so that data will get returned once promise fullfilled.. do look at the udpated answer..I was missing arrow function `=>` in `.then`..

Comment: Sorry, i didn't realize you updated your answer already.  This is what i get if i do it with just `.once('value').then(...)`

Error: `Query.once failed: Was called with 1 argument. Expects at least 2.` so i might have to do it with a callback but I'm not sure how

Comment: Looks like i might be using older firebase SDK that doesn't support that syntax for `.once()`

Comment: Yes..you are using older version..I think you might need to update typings.ts(not pretty sure). The link you referred in a answer has same paatern..which I've used..

Comment: Very useful! Thank you